# gnuplot to gnuplot.py

Tags: python, gnuplot

Can somebody help me convert this gnuplot command to gnuplot.py

gnuplot command(works fine in gnuplot interpreter):

```
plot 'immigration.dat' using 2:xtic(1) ti col, '' u 3 ti col, '' u 4 ti col, '' u 5 ti col
```

I have tried this in file.py:

```
import Gnuplot

g = Gnuplot.Gnuplot(debug=1)

g.plot(Gnuplot.File('immigration.dat', using='2:xtic(1) ti col, '' u 3 ti col, '' u 4 ti col, '' u 5 ti col'))
```

but results in error:"line 0: undefined variable: u", syntax issue i guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import Gnuplot

g = Gnuplot.Gnuplot(debug=1)

g.plot(Gnuplot.File('immigration.dat', using="2:xtic(1) ti col, '' u 3 ti col, '' u 4 ti col, '' u 5 ti col"))
```

You were mixing quotes.

Comment: Great! thanks, i just checked it with a sleep(), thanks again